# Passing multiple values using javascript onclick()

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I want to pass multiples values using onclick. See example page1.php and page2.php

page1.php

```
<script>
function call_function(fila){
    $.post("<?php echo url_for('http://....com/page2.php');?>",
    { 
        rterc: $("#rterc_" + fila).val(),  
        eterc: $("#eterc_" + fila).val(),
        CSBTEMAIL : $("#CSBTEMAIL).val(),
    },  
}
```

```
 <table><tr><td>
<?php 
if ($deuda['estado'] == 0){?>
 <a href="#" onclick="call_function('<?php echo $fila;?>')" class="btn btn-default" role="button" >
  <input type="hidden" id="rterc_<?php echo $fila;?>" value="<?php echo $deuda['rterc'];?>" />
  <input type="hidden" id="eterc_<?php echo $fila;?>" value="<?php echo $deuda['eterc'];?>" /> 
  <input type="hidden" id="CSBTEMAIL" value="<?php echo $correo;?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="CSMDD35" value="<?php echo $tipodoc;?>" />
  <input type="hidden" id="CSMDD36" value="<?php echo $nrodoc;?>" />       
  <input type="hidden" id="CSBTEMAIL" value="<?php echo $correo;?>" /> 
  <input type="hidden" id="CSMDD35" value="<?php echo $tipodoc;?>" /> 
  <input type="hidden" id="CSMDD36" value="<?php echo $nrodoc;?>" /> 
 <i class="icon icon-plus text-info">Pagar</i></a><?php }
 else
 {  
 echo "Passed";}?>
```

page2.
I need get these values of page1. How I get the valueS?
$email = $_POST['CSBTEMAIL'];

Is it correct? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: And what you have isn't working?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for. What values do you want to pass to what function when what is clicked?

Comment: please clarify your question, I don't understand what exactly your are trying to do, there's no onclick event in the provided code.

Comment: according to what we know, you are passing multiple value to your page. what's the question

Comment: You really need to take a few minutes to read through [ask] then write a proper explanation of what exactly it is you are trying to do and problems you have doing it

Comment: I was editing my thread. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply send the values using a link. Example change your href to `"page2.php?value1=value&value2=value" and then use $value1 = $_GET['value1'];` to get the value.

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but there you go.

Comment: There are 24 values, is it correct pass them to get?

Comment: You will have one hell of a link.. where are you getting the values from that you echo in the hidden fields? - You coulf maybe use SESSIONS to store the values and access from page two or even GLOBALS to do that.

Comment: I going try. Perhaps I'll send it using js

Comment: Let me know if I should post an example using SESSIONS as well as GLOBALS.. I really think this would be a good option.. remember if the user has JS disabled in his browser your values would not be sent. Keep that in mind

Comment: Good.. let me know if you need more help..

Comment: everything ok for now! thanks so much!

Comment: Great stuff! If any of what I said helped you in any way. Kindly accept the answer. ;)